# swift what is the best way to retrieve snap nodes from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve `senderId` from this snapshot. `ChildAdded` must be use and the FirRef below must stay the same.

this is my current func to retrieve the data from firebase

```
 func retrieveInfo(completion: (result: String)->()) {
       fireBaseAPI().childRef("version_one/frontEnd/post/\(self.previousViewMessageId)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in



     })
```

This is the snapshot being printed

```
Snap (postDescription) Description here
Snap (postTitle) What do you need done
Snap (receiverId) RYclS9Qy4vRr6gp8JbfoztSYQnL2
Snap (senderId) niZKOcnoh0cdFpF2K26bxugw1hz1
Snap (status) 0
Snap (messages) {
    "-KRqOqd2POJYpCNSSumG" =     {
        mediaType = TEXT;
        senderDisplayName = "";
        senderId = niZKOcnoh0cdFpF2K26bxugw1hz1;
        text = iPhone;
    };
}
```

What is the best way to retrieve any of the nodes that says Snap

This is the firebase Json

```
 {
  "version_one" : {
    "frontEnd" : {
      "post" : {
        "-KRoucvwAs1jBaoNahDP" : {
          "messages" : {
            "-KRqOqd2POJYpCNSSumG" : {
              "mediaType" : "TEXT",
              "senderDisplayName" : "",
              "senderId" : "niZKOcnoh0cdFpF2K26bxugw1hz1",
              "text" : "iPhone"
            }
          },
          "postDescription" : "Description here",
          "postTitle" : "What do you need done",
          "receiverId" : "RYclS9Qy4vRr6gp8JbfoztSYQnL2",
          "senderId" : "niZKOcnoh0cdFpF2K26bxugw1hz1",
          "status" : 0
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func retrieveInfo(completion: (result: String)->()) {
   fireBaseAPI().childRef("version_one/frontEnd/post/\(self.previousViewMessageId)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in
    if let messageDict = snapshot.value in [String:AnyObject]{

                  let senderId = messageDict["senderId"] as! String
              .....


      }

 })
```